# Почему не работает wildcard module declaration?

Tags: typescript

Почему не работает такой способ декларации: `declare module "*!text" {}` ?

Цель - использовать контент файла в переменной:

```
import layout = require("/js/views/layouts/wnd.html!text");
```

или так:

```
import layout from "/js/views/layouts/wnd.html!text";
```

Если же делать декларацию так: `declare module "/js/views/layouts/wnd.html!text" {}` -
то все работает, а если использовать такой метод `"*!text"` то получаю ошибку `cannot find module`. Как заставить работать такой шаблон `"*!text"`?

Ссылка на [пример из документации](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#wildcard-module-declarations)

Использую systemJS с этим [плагином для загрузки текстовых файлов](https://github.com/systemjs/plugin-text)

Версия TS - 2.0.6

Comment: какую версию ts используете?

Comment: @anstarovoyt Версия typescript - 2.0

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что это вообще должно работать?

Comment: @Grundy потому что здесь есть пример: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#wildcard-module-declarations

Comment: добавь эту ссылку в сам вопрос. и обрати внимание на первую строчку там: _Some **module loaders** such as **SystemJS** and **AMD** allow non-JavaScript content to be imported._

Comment: @Grundy я использую systemjs, все грузит если явно декларировать модуль. А если задаем маску - ошибка возникает на этапе компиляции, я описал это в самом вопросе

Comment: суть в том, что там используются не просто имена файлов, а лоадеры: `json`, `text`

Comment: @Grundy Да, я использую лоадер text, но опять же - ОШИБКА НА ЭТАПЕ КОМПИЛЯЦИИ, а не загрузки самого файла

Comment: _declare module "*.html"_ - не вижу тут использование лоадера text

Comment: _ОШИБКА НА ЭТАПЕ КОМПИЛЯЦИИ, а не загрузки самого файла_ попробуй _import page from "*.html"_

Comment: @Grundy извиняюсь, вопрос поправил. Способ `import page from` так же не работает!